# how to display a full XML in an html page with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

I load an xml

```
        $.ajax({
            url: '../rest/',
            dataType: "xml",
            success: showXML

        });

        function showXML(xml) {
            $("#output").text((xml));   
        }
```

but he doesn't show the xml in my output div

he shows this: **[object Document]**
what needs to be done so he will simple display the xml?

Comment: Use CDATA, otherwise you won't be able to handle XML inside your document.

Comment: I think it won't be that simple, even if you set the datatype to text I think you probably still need to properly format certain characters such as `<` and `>` character.

Comment: @RosdiKasim jquerys `text` method would handle that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you set the `dataType` to `xml` jquery will automatically give you an object for the data-parameter of your success callback.

Try using this signature:

```
function showXML(xml, textStatus, jqXHR)
```

and:

```
$("#output").text(jqXHR.responseText);
```

Comment: still outputs [object Document]

Comment: @AndyJacobs try `jqXHR.responseText`  I did not have the possibility to test this, so I wasn't too sure which one was the right one.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `dataType` to `"html"` or `"text"`. If that doesn't work, you may need to do what was said in the comment to your post.